# Field validation for not null or empty is not triggering

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to send messaging to the user that a field is required if they fail to input a value.  I want the error to be displayed on the field itself, rather than a global error message at the top of the page.

If I do not enter any data into the form, it still allows submission.  However, if I do not enter a username but I do enter mismatched passwords, the username field receives the validation message "Passwords do not match".

So, it appears to me, that for some reason my code to check if the input is null is not passing as True and so the function continues to my next condition.

Why isn't this function catching nulls?

```
<form action="/register" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text"
               oninput="checkNull(this)" id="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" oninput="checkNull(this)"
               id="password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password"
               oninput="check(this)" id="confirmPassword">
    </div>
    <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
        function check(input) {
            if (input.value != document.getElementById('password').value) {
                input.setCustomValidity('Passwords do not match');
            } else {
                input.setCustomValidity('');
            }
        }
        if (input.value == "" || input.value == null) {
                input.setCustomValidity('This field is required');
            } 
            else {
                input.setCustomValidity('');
            }
    </script>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

I've tried some additional troubleshooting.  I split my functions out, one to check for matching passwords, one to check for no input.  I realized that by calling them in the same function I was comparing each to the password which is a problem.

As a sanity check, I then set to check for a specific string "foo".  When passing in "foo", the error displays as expected, so I know at least the function is getting called.

I then tried to use "===" to compare the value rather than "==", but that didn't work either.

Code updated to reflect most recent changes.

Comment: You should add required field in input tag

Comment: `input.value` will never be `null`, there's no need to check for it.

Comment: What does your `setCustomValidity()` function do?

Comment: It just displays an error message.  I didn't create that function, it's just a standard JS function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When submit your form, it is not calling `check()` function. So, if you not touch any `input`, they will not be validated.

You can solve this by adding `onsubmit="return validate()"` to `<form />` tag:

```html
<form action="/register" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
```

Your validation function could be simple as:

```
var isValid = true;

function validate() {
  isValid = true;
  document.querySelectorAll('.form-control').forEach(check);

  return isValid;
}
```

Notice the `return` keyword. **When return value is `false` the submitting action will be cancelled.** `check()` function should also mutate `isValid` variable:

```
function check(input) {
  if (input.value == "" || input.value == null) {
    input.setCustomValidity('This field is required');
    isValid = false;
  }
  else if (input.type == 'password' && input.value != document.getElementById('password').value) {
    input.setCustomValidity('Passwords do not match');
    isValid = false;
  }
  else {
    input.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}
```

Also, you should only check if passwords are the same if you are validating a password input.
You can accomplish this by adding the extra condition to password validation: `input.type == 'password'`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your check method **onchange**, if you do not enter any text in the username field, your check method will not be called. So, the simple way to do this is to add required attribute on all your fields.

If you want to do it using JS, look at [onsubmit](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp) method that gets triggered when the form's submit button is clicked.

Also, you should have three different methods for validating each of your fields. It will be hard to maintain and you will be cramping up one method with various checks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using deprecated techniques here.. You should never attach a function to a form element in-line (within the html tag).

When it comes to checking password on keyup, you could use something like this with jquery:

```
var pwInputs = $(this).find('input[type=password]');

$('input[type=password]').keyup(() => {
        pwarr = new Array();
        pwInputs.each(function() {
            pwarr.push($(this));
        });
        if (pwarr[0].val() != pwarr[1].val()) {
                // Do work
        }
        if (pwarr[0].val() == null || pwarr[0].val() == "" & pwarr[1].val() == null || pwarr[1].val() == "") {
                // Do Work
        }
});
```

You could use jquery in a similar fashion to check values on submit.

```
$('#formid').on('submit', function() { // Do work })
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll look into this.  I'm just learning to code, so I was not aware of this.  Thanks again!